# Selenium how to pass the WebDriver with options to other function [Kotlin]

Tags: selenium, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently coding a bot and for that I need a changed user agent, which is only done with options, like this:

```
val options = ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 ",  "(KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/18.1 Mobile/16B92 Safari/605.1.15")
val driver : WebDriver = ChromeDriver(options)
```

However, that needs to be enclosed in fun main(), because there is the "options.addArguments" portion. If I didn't need the options, I could just put it outside and every function would be able to access the "driver" variable

Any tips for how do I make the "driver" variable accessible to all functions? I really don't want to put everything into main()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DriverManager object.

```
object DriverManager {
    lateinit var driver: WebDriver
}
```

And init it once in a main().

```
fun main() {
    DriverManager.driver = ChromeDriver(options)
}
```